# iOS 8 Extensions don't appear in the Share Dialogue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I'm building a Share Extension to my App.
My problem is that it doesn't show up in the Share List, until I go to 'More' screen, disable then enable it.
I have tried all 'NSExtensionActivationRule' combinations including TRUEPREDICATE.

PS. Same thing happens for Action Extension. Tried on both simulator and device. All other enabled extensions show up all the time.

Comment: I feel like it's a bug in the OS since I created a brand new app with only a Share Extension and got the same issue.

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution for this? I have the same issue (except TRUEPREDICATE will show it without the toggle). I'm on iOS 8.4 and Xcode 6.4.

Comment: @Otter207 The extension worked once I submitted the app to the AppStore (AppStore version)

Comment: I figured that may be the case, but I'm relieved to hear it from someone else! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you have  'NSExtensionActivationRule'  = Truepredicate when you released the app to the app store?

Comment: @Slartibartfast No, I had it as I wanted it to function. Actually 'NSExtensionActivationRule' = Truepredicate will cause your app to get rejected.

Comment: Sorry, ios noob, what should be the value? Is it necessary?